# Reduce two Scala methods, that only differ in one Object Type

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have the following two methods, using objects from Apache Spark.

```
  def SVMModelScoring(sc: SparkContext, scoringDataset: String, modelFileName: String): RDD[(Double, Double)] = {
    val model = SVMModel.load(sc, modelFileName)

    val scoreAndLabels = 
      MLUtils.loadLibSVMFile(sc, scoringDataset).randomSplit(Array(0.1), seed = 11L)(0).map { point =>
        val score = model.predict(point.features)
        (score, point.label)
      }
    return scoreAndLabels
  }

  def DecisionTreeScoring(sc: SparkContext, scoringDataset: String, modelFileName: String): RDD[(Double, Double)] = {
    val model = DecisionTreeModel.load(sc, modelFileName)

    val scoreAndLabels = 
      MLUtils.loadLibSVMFile(sc, scoringDataset).randomSplit(Array(0.1), seed = 11L)(0).map { point =>
        val score = model.predict(point.features)
        (score, point.label)
      }
    return scoreAndLabels
  }
```

My previous attempts to merge these functions have resulted in errors surround model.predict.

Is there a way I can use model as a parameter that is weakly typed in Scala?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Disclaimer** - I've never used Apache Spark.

It looks to me like the only difference between the two methods is the way the `model` is instantiated. It's unfortunate that the two `model` instances don't actually share a common trait that provides `predict(...)` but we can still make this work by pulling out the part that changes - the `scorer`:

```
def scoreWith(sc: SparkContext, scoringDataset: String)(scorer: (Vector)=>Double): RDD[(Double, Double)] = {
  MLUtils.loadLibSVMFile(sc, scoringDataset).randomSplit(Array(0.1), seed = 11L)(0).map { point =>
    val score = scorer(point.features)
    (score, point.label)
  }
}
```

Now we can get the previous functionality with:

```
def svmScorer(sc: SparkContext, scoringDataset:String, modelFileName:String) =
  scoreWith(sc: SparkContext, scoringDataset:String)(SVMModel.load(sc, modelFileName).predict)

def dtScorer(sc: SparkContext, scoringDataset:String, modelFileName:String) =
  scoreWith(sc: SparkContext, scoringDataset:String)(DecisionTreeModel.load(sc, modelFileName).predict)
```

Comment: Very promising... But my IDE(Eclipse) is throwing an error for `Vector` in the first line of your provided code(I'm trying to debug but in case you might know...)

Comment: "type Vector takes type parameters"

Comment: Your IDE has imported Scala's `Vector[T]` collection class instead of Spark's: [org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector)